# Polygon subtraction error. Altium rules are ignored

Tags: altium

I need to subtract a small polygon from my base polygon. However, after subtraction, my rules are ignored by the Altium. what is my mistake?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Something definitely seems fishy about this. How are your rules for polygon clearance set up? Did they change?

Comment: Yep. No, rules are fixed but this behavior is strange.